# How can you force google openid to authenticate only from a specific google app email?

Tags: google-workspace, openid

I am trying to make sense of the way google openid works to no avail for the moment. I have a google app for business with its own domain and an email there. I also have my personal gmail account.

When I log in into both accounts then try to authenticate on a random website with google's openid url https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ I am asked to choose between my gmail and my domain email. whichever I choose, the auth succeeds (I was able to create 2 different accounts on stackoverflow, one for both emails). I would like to find an URL which "autoselects" the email which belongs to domain.com and ignores any other.

Reading up on the way google's authentication works (
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sso/openid_reference_implementation , https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/UXFedLogin/summary and https://sites.google.com/site/oauthgoog/fedlogininterp/openiddiscovery ),  I tried authenticating with https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?hd=domain.com then with https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/site-xrds?ns=2&hd=domain.com this does redirect me to google's auth and only allows my domain.com email. however, after having successfully singed into google, I don't get authenticated on websites.

I tried with https://superuser.com/ and with http://www.openid-ldap.org/test.php to no avail.Both failed, and the second one tells me :

```
OpenID authentication failed: No OpenID information found at http://domain.com/openid?id=114987420251804701387
```

Any idea what I should do ? If possible, I would prefer not to have to setup a webserver on my domain.

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to setup an OpenID authentication system?

Answer (score -1):

Almost 8 years late but, you have to send the `login_hint`param in the authorization request if you want to authorize a particular email.

That been said, don't quote me on this one but google accounts auto selects your last active account from the account chooser depending on the context.

So if you are signing up it will always show you the account chooser, but if you are logging in maybe it will just do an auto login depending of you activity, if that makes sense.

Answer (score -4):

Try giving your full email id, ie, if your company mail id is abc@example.com and example.com use google business mail, then while authenticating you should give username as abc@example.com instead of just abc. This will work for gtalk too.

Comment: I don't understand your answer: I don't "give" my email anywhere. I give my openid endpoint to the website I want to authenticate this will redirect me to a google page where I can choose between 2 different and complete emails. I would like to "craft" the openid endpoint url so that google automatically choose the email adress of a given domain.